# Why does canIuse.com not list google versions less than 4?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-support

Looking up [contenteditable on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable) and hitting show all to see the earliest version of browsers when this feature has been supported, I see Google Chrome is only listed back to version 4. Earlier versions are not shown. Does this have a particular reason or does caniuse just not test on these versions?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess. But if I were them I would pick the earliest version that supported the most common platforms; coincidentally it happens to be [4.0.249.30](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.fr/2009/12/beta-update-linux-mac-and-windows.html).

**Rationale**

- it wouldn't make sense to have a separate column to distinguish the Windows-only flavour of early versions of Chrome (unlike Chrome for Android)
- when you care about interoperability the big 3 (Mac, Windows and GNU/Linux) constitute the main targets, in that regard Chrome 4 could be considered their first desktop agnostic release